# Why is my Char* empty after filling with integers?

Tags: c++, networking, char

I would like to save several integers in a char pointer and then send this pointer with sendto (winsock2). Unfortunately my char pointer always only contains "\n". Right at the creation and also after filling. What have I done wrong?

```
uint32_t id = getID();
uint8_t inputType = getInputType(), inputValue = getInputValue();
char* inputBuffer = new char[6];
inputBuffer[0] = (id >> 24) & 0x000000ff;
inputBuffer[1] = (id >> 16) & 0x000000ff;
inputBuffer[2] = (id >> 8) & 0x000000ff;
inputBuffer[3] = (id >> 0) & 0x000000ff;
inputBuffer[4] = (inputType >> 0) & 0x000000ff;
inputBuffer[5] = (inputValue >> 0) & 0x000000ff;

// Send to Server
sendto(socket, inputBuffer, 6, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&srvAddr_In, sizeof(SOCKADDR));

delete[] inputBuffer;
```

id, inputType and inputValue always contain a valid number.
For example I tried id = 10, inputType = 4 and inputValue = 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You char pointer does not contain `'\n'`, at least not in the first position anyway. Rather it contains `NUL` as the first element, so it will appear blank when displayed as a C-style string.

That's because the least significant 8 bits, obtained with  `& 0xff`, of `10` right-shifted 24 times is zero.

There are data in the `char` buffer. Note in particular that `inputBuffer[3]` has the value 10. It's just that you can't see it with your favourite string viewer!

Finally, consider using `unsigned char` rather than `char`, as the signedness of `char` is platform-dependent. (And so is the complementing scheme of `char` if `signed` prior to C++14).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Showoff. Assuming ASCII though ;-)

Comment: At first I tried memcpy, but it didn't work either. After searching in the internet, I found several entries where it is recommended to only work with >> and & when it comes to sending with sendto

Comment: @TimoSpielberger: The issue is how you are *viewing* the character buffer. There are non-zero elements in it. I'm going to take out the `memcpy` recommendation as it indeed doesn't provide a fix. There is nothing to fix - other than using `unsigned char`.

Comment: Now i know what you mean. Thank you. But how can I use an unsigned char with sendto? If I try, there is an error, which says that I can't convert from unsigned char* to const char*

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<>` to the rescue ;)

Comment: @Waqar: Do you mean that I should do this before the sendto? Is there any advantage then? Because then the unsigned char will be converted back to the platform-dependent char or not?

Comment: you have to use it right before where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it step by step to see what's wrong:

Assuming,

```
uint32_t id = 100
```

Bit representation of id will be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 01100100
```

Step 1.

Statement: `inputBuffer[0] = (id >> 24) & 0x000000ff;`
Acutally you can just simplify this to: `(id >> 24)`

Result: `inputBuffer[0] = 00000000`

Step 2.

Statement: `inputBuffer[0] = (id >> 16) & 0x000000ff;`

Result: `inputBuffer[1] = 00000000`

Step 3.

Statement: `inputBuffer[0] = (id >> 8) & 0x000000ff;`

Result: `inputBuffer[2] = 00000000`

Step 4.

Statement: `inputBuffer[0] = (id >> 0) & 0x000000ff;`

Result: `inputBuffer[3] = 01100100` // 100

If you try to print `inputBuffer` at this stage, it will not print anything since the first position contains `\0`. This is perfectly fine. You just need to be careful on the receiving end of the message.

Recieving end:

```
uint32_t id = (uint32_t)data[0] << 24)  |
              ((uint32_t)data[1] << 16) |
              ((uint32_t)data[2] << 8)  |
              ((uint32_t)data[3]);
//id == 100
```